# Updating multiple rows with the same Ordernumber

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-update, rows

[image]

I'm trying to update values of two tables such as from dataGridview
Order table and Orderdetail table as shown in my image.

It's working to update Order table but updating OrderdDetail table is not working. I want to update all rows with the same OrderNr. I get OrderDetail values from dataGridView. Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateOrder(int paymentTypes)
{       
        try
        {
            string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open(); 
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Orders] SET Amount = @Amount, Tax = @Tax , ToPay = @ToPay WHERE OrderNr = @OrderNumber", conn))
                {                                             
                    // This First table Orders updating fine
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtAmount.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tax", txtTax.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToPay", txtToPay.Text); 
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                 

                }
            // Here begin for OrderDetails table and not working to update.
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCart.Rows)
                {
                     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [OrdersItems] SET OrderNr = @OrderNumber, ProductId = @ProductId, Quantity = @Quantity,  WHERE OrderNr = @OrderNumber AND ProductId = @ProductId", conn))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value)); 
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", txtOrderNumber.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["ProductId "].Value));

                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                            
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Updating successfully !", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

First you have a syntax error in your query

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE [OrdersItems] 
    SET OrderNr = @OrderNumber, ProductId = @ProductId, Quantity = @Quantity,  
    WHERE OrderNr = @OrderNumber AND ProductId = @ProductId", conn))
```

There is a comma before  the WHERE statement that you should remove.

Second, the first query is missing the parameter for OrderNumber.

Third point. 
In OleDb parameters are positional, even if you can name them you should put them in the same order in which they appear in the query and you need to put it again if you use them two times (OrderNumber & ProductID appear both in the SET part and in the WHERE)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", txtOrderNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["ProductId "].Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value)); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", txtOrderNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["ProductId "].Value));
```

However you don't need to update the ProductID and the OrderNumber. They cannot change otherwise this query could not find the rows that you want to update.

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE [OrdersItems] 
               SET Quantity = @Quantity
               WHERE OrderNr = @OrderNumber AND ProductId = @ProductId", conn))
```

with only three parameters in the correct order

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value)); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", txtOrderNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["ProductId "].Value));
```